# Creating an Embedded installer plugin for macOS application - how to pass parameters when run from command line

Tags: objective-c, macos, package, installation, macos-installer

I've created an installer using `Packages` with an additional plugin that has 2 text fields whose values are being printed upon moving forward to the next step on the installation wizard.

Here's the code :

MyInstallerPage.h

```
#import <InstallerPlugins/InstallerPlugins.h>

@interface MyInstallerPane : InstallerPane <NSTextFieldDelegate>

@end
```

MyInstallerPane.m

```
#import "MyInstallerPane.h"

@interface MyInstallerPane() {

}

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *firstNameTextField;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *lastNameTextField;

@end

@implementation MyInstallerPane

- (NSString *)title
{
    return [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] localizedStringForKey:@"PaneTitle" value:nil table:nil];
}

- (void)didEnterPane:(InstallerSectionDirection)dir {
    self.firstNameTextField.delegate = self;
    self.lastNameTextField.delegate = self;
}

- (void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)obj {
    NSLog(@"First name: %@", self.firstNameTextField.stringValue);
    NSLog(@"Last name : %@",
          self.lastNameTextField.stringValue);
}

@end
```

I wonder how do I set those text fields when running my the installer from command line using command `/usr/sbin/installer -pkg ./MyPackage.pkg -target /`

In the UI mode, when run my package using the command `open myPackage.pkg`, and I get the plugin window whereas I simply need to enter those values in the appropriate text fields.

[image]

One workaround for this problem is to use an additional script that perform the following steps instead of running the installer directly from command line.

1. gets those values (first+last name) as input parameters and write them to special file.
2. run the installer command `installer -pkg...`.
3. From within the installer. The plugin will check if textBoxes are empty (which is correct in the case of non-ui installation. In this case, it will lookup those values in the special file.

Comment: can you guide how to store these values in a file from a plugin and execute the script by using these values as an input. I have post install script in my installer which will use user email as an input value.

Comment: Hi, you can use `writeToFile` ( `NSString` method) from each of your input values like `self.firstNameTextField.stringValue ` and that read the file from postinstall script using bash command like `cat yourFilePath` - just don't forget to remove the file in the end.

Comment: what will be the path for this file? I mean if i create it from my installer plugin and write some data into it. where this file will be stored on my mac machine?